# Blender 2.8 Multires Sculpt with texture on

Tags: sculpting

In the newest build of 2.8 as of today (June 8th 2019).
I am trying to sculpt an object while also having a specific texture show on the same object. I cannot find any way to do that. As soon as I switch to sculpt mode I get some sort of matcap material and I cannot get a texture to show up in any renderer under any settings I tried. Is there I solution?

EDIT if you want to take a stab at solving this please make sure you have an object with Multires modifier applied to it.

EDIT 2 Looks like it's a bug that's been reported already
https://developer.blender.org/T63581

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but if you change to Lookdev, you will see your texture.

[image]

Good Luck

Comment: That would be perfect but for some reason I don't see the texture in sculpt mode.

Comment: Aha... it does work in sculpt mode but not when I have multires modifier on.

Answer (score 1):

An option at this time is to create a Matcap an install it inside blender.

You can do a quick one if you render your texture on a Sphere with some lights.

[image]

hope that helps

Comment: Thanks interesting approach but the texture mapping wouldn't be accurate, which I need.